# Android PackageManger.getLaunchIntentForPackage() not throwing documented exception

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I try to get a launch intent from a third party package from the `PackageManager`. According to the documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage(java.lang.String)), it throws a `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException` if the given package name cannot be found on the system and it returns `null` if the package does not contain a launch activity.

When I try to catch the exception, I get a compilation error:

```
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try{
        Intent launchAppIntent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("somePackageName");
        //...
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException exception){

    }
```

> java: exception
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException is never
>   thrown in body of corresponding try statement

I think that one possibility might be that the behavior of that method changed and it returns always `null` instead of throwing an exception. But then, should I still wrap a try block around the call?

How should I proceed solving that issue?

I am currently building against Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation is outdated.

"throws NameNotFoundException" has been removed from the method in [Android 1.6](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java/?v=diff&id2=1.5_r4#576) (API Level 4).

the current implementation in [ApplicationPackageManager.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java) from Android 4.0 onwards does also not throw any exception.

You can safely remove the try catch.

P.S.: I know, the answer is a bit delayed, but I stumbled across the same, so why not share it here.